# Possible to add javascript to a PDF to communicate with a parent window?

Tags: javascript, pdf, iframe, pdf-generation

I am currently trying to find a way so that whenever a Link is selected in a specific PDF file to be able to know which URL it points to and do something based on the selection. I've looked online for pdf libraries such as [Adobe Acrobat SDK](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf) and the [Docotic.Pdf Library](http://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/help/samples.aspx) by bitmiracle, but haven't been able to find a solution to this. Can a PDF document opened in lets say, an Iframe inside an HTML window, communicate with functions defined in the HTML window? In my case I am not constructing the initial PDF using any pdf creator. My pdf is being converted from a word document and then would be opened using some pdf viewers or similar tools.

Comment: Adobe has done a lot in the last few years to help developers and content authors make PDFs more "interactive", but I'm not sure what exactly that provides to the developer in terms of toolset. My guess is that javascript is not an option.

Comment: Can a PDF document opened in lets say, an Iframe inside an HTML window, communicate with functions defined in the HTML window? No, as far as I know you cannot do that. The best you can get is to submit a form to a web server, or to call a webservice using javascript.

Comment: Using the native PDF viewer, no. But using PDF.js to render the pdf, you can.

Comment: Any link to some sample code or anything similar levi? I'll be looking up see what I can find on PDF.js. Thanks!

Comment: You might explore a bit what the launchURL() method allows; it may work or not, but the javascript: protocol could help a little bit (at least for talking from the PDF to the browser).

Comment: Thanks max, I'll take a look at that. I'll be posting anything interesting I find.